# Collision Detection - Goblin XNA

Tags: opencv, xna

Im working on a Project based on Goblin XNA.You can get an idea on what I really want do by checking this image  http://img97.imageshack.us/i/markerdetectioncopy.jpg/

I manage to retreive finger cordinates using open cv and pass it to XNA. What I want to do is to see if there is a collision between the finger cordinates and the object generated by Goblin.

I would really appriciate if anyone could give me some guidance on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need the 2d coordinates from 3d object (using Viewport.Unproject function). Then you only have to do a simple circle collision between the two points.